# Openvino, how to get detection result?

Tags: python, inference, openvino

I convertet my yoloV5 weights to ONNX, and loaded the onnx file in netron.

these are the properties of my model:

[image]

This Model has been converted with model optimizer to be used with openvino.

Its my understanding (please correct me if I am wrong) that "output" is the detection result, and 345, 403, 461 are intermediate outputs in the network..

I dont seem to be able to understand how to get the detection result (detected class..) and the data for the boundingbox...

this is my code:

```
 ie = IECore()
    devices = ie.available_devices
    for device in devices:
        device_name = ie.get_metric(device_name=device, metric_name="FULL_DEVICE_NAME")
        print(f"{device}: {device_name}")
    classification_model_xml = "best.xml"
    t1 = time_sync()
    net = ie.read_network(model=classification_model_xml)
    exec_net = ie.load_network(network=net, device_name="CPU")
    input_layer = next(iter(net.input_info))
    output_layer = net.outputs['output']
    image_filename = "test.jpg"
    image = cv2.imread(image_filename)
    print(f"input layout: {net.input_info[input_layer].layout}")
    print(f"input precision: {net.input_info[input_layer].precision}")
    print(f"input shape: {net.input_info[input_layer].tensor_desc.dims}")
    print(f"output layout: {output_layer.layout}")
    print(f"output precision: {output_layer.precision}")
    print(f"output shape: {output_layer.shape}")
    N, C, H, W = net.input_info[input_layer].tensor_desc.dims
    print(N, C, H, W)
    image.shape
    input_data = np.expand_dims(np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1)), 0).astype(np.float32)
    input_data.shape

    input_key = next(iter(exec_net.input_info))
    output_key = next(iter(exec_net.outputs.keys()))
    result = exec_net.infer(inputs={input_key: input_data})
    result_index = np.argmax(result)
    t2 = time_sync()
    output = result[4]
    result_index = np.argmax(result)
    print(result_index)
    self.LabelTimeMs.setText("{:.2f}".format((t2-t1)*1000))
```

how can I access the recognized class and the boudning box data?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the 2020.4 release, [OpenVINO™ supports reading native ONNX models](https://docs.openvino.ai/2021.1/openvino_docs_IE_DG_ONNX_Support.html), so you don't have to convert the ONNX model into IR using Model Optimizer.

To ensure your model is actually workable with OpenVINO, you may run it with [OpenVINO Benchmark Python Tool](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_inference_engine_tools_benchmark_tool_README.html). You **should not** receive any error when running this with your model. (You can ignore warnings as long as there's no error).

It is recommended to use OpenVINO [Inference Engine Samples](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_IE_DG_Samples_Overview.html) especially if you are a beginner. This [Object Detection Python Demo](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/omz_demos_object_detection_demo_python.html?) might be suitable for your use case.

You may refer to the sample source code to see how the OpenVINO Inference Engine API is used, the creation of bounding boxes, the handling of models, propagation methods, etc. From here, you could adapt the code according to your aim.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. except for the benchmark python tool, starting from samples and adapting the code is exactly what i did. Unfortunately I am not able to make it run as i'´d expect and postet my code. there must be an error in m code, but I am not able to find what I am doing wrong, and was hoping on help on that. Thank you Best regards

Comment: Did you manage to run your model with the Benchmark Python Tool? just to ensure your YOLOv5 model is workable with OpenVINO Inference Engine API. Hence, there should be no problem with any inferencing with OpenVINO. Regarding your custom code and understanding how to get the detection result, this is not solely relies on OpenVINO as it's a general technical information that you'll need to figure out on your own, such as https://towardsdatascience.com/object-detection-with-10-lines-of-code-d6cb4d86f606

Comment: @sharkyenergy, there are a lot of other ways/libraries but note that OpenVINO comes with OpenCV. The samples including the one I suggested in my first reply are using OpenCV. This OpenCV tutorial might also help you to understand better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXDD7-EnGBY

Comment: The benchmark tool worked without errors, just some warnings. The ONNX file works with CPU but fails with GPU. the xml file created with the optimizer works with CPU and GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Not that long ago, OpenVINO-inference sample code has been added to the Ultralytics repo, which you might find useful:

https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/pull/6057 "OpenVINO Export"  (Dec 22, 2021)

https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/pull/6179 "Add OpenVINO inference" (Jan 4, 2022)

https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/pull/6739 "YOLOv5 v6.1 release" (Feb-22, 2022)